# Ribbon button still visible after hide from code

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I try to hide a button after click on it, i try following code :

```
btnEdit.Visible = false;
```

but the button still visible, it hide once i click on it

full code :

```
    void SwitchMenu(bool showEdit)
    {
        boxEdit.Visible = showEdit;                                    
        foreach (var item in boxEdit.Items)
        {
            item.Visible = showEdit;
        }
        boxCreate.Visible = !showEdit;
        foreach (var item in boxCreate.Items)
        {
            item.Visible = !showEdit;
        }                                  
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code?  Where is this line in reference in your code.  Are you sure it is getting hit (try putting a breakpoint on it and seeing if it hits).

Comment: added to question, yes breakpoints added and it hit, in debug mood visible = false but it still show in menu, it disable after click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are an issue with Box visibility, removed box solve my issue.